# Utilize same Google Maps key for multiple packages

Tags: android, package, google-maps-android-api-2

When creating a key for Google Maps version 2 one must specify the name of a package. My question is, can the resulting key later on be used for different packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give informations about your application to obtain the key.

It can be used for 1 "certificate". According Google :

> "Applications that use the same certificate can use the same API key.
>   However, the recommended practice is to sign each of your applications
>   with a different certificate and get a different key for each one."